# Шифрование строки по ключу

Tags: защита, php, java, шифрование

Здравствуйте, возникла необходимость безопасно передать строку от PHP скрипта до Java приложения. Сразу я подумал про шифровку по секретному ключу. Посоветуйте код шифровки строки на вебсервере с PHP и код расшифровки на Java.

Comment: Больше информации надо... Не особо понятно что ты хочешь и зачем? Синхронное, ассинхронное шифрование тебе надо? Может просто https подойдет, для многих клиентов рассылка нужна или....

Comment: base64_encode()

Comment: @Asen, это не шифрование, а кодирование (причем широкоизвестное).


@sashok724, если симметричное шифрование подходит, то вырабатывайте на клиенте и сервере гамму на основе Вашего секретного ключа и известного им обоим сеансового ключа (токена). 

Дальше шифруйте (и дешифруйте) Ваши строки, например XOR-ом с этой гаммой.

При передаче (чтобы передавать только ASCII) можно применять base64_encode().

Comment: @avp, в том то и дело что я не нашел как закодировать строку по XOR в php скрипте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@sashok724](/users/6893/sashok724),

Запрос Google: "php xor шифрование" и секунд через 10 смотрите, например

[Обратимое XOR шифрование текста со случайной гаммой](http://denik.od.ua/xor_text_encoding/)

IMHO там доступно изложено.