# Как зашифровать данные в php?

Tags: php, шифрование

Мне нужна передать важную информацию по API. Как можно зашифровать данные для защиты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уже обсуждалось что-то подобное: [Шифрование строки по ключу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/119191/php-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%83)

Есть также функции шифрования [Mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mcrypt.php), но для этого нужно подключать php_mcrypt.dll

Comment: А если использовать OpenSSL?

Comment: Всё зависит от задач.
По сути, нет ничего невозможного. Библиотеки есть https://github.com/ivan-novakov/php-openssl-crypt
Единственное нужно внимательно почитать что там требуется для установки http://www.php.net/manual/ru/openssl.installation.php

Comment: Спасибо большое, мне ещё очень помогла ваша ссылка =)